# Fill in mandatory fields on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamic table https://jsfiddle.net/vc5dbtw9/8/ that is generated through my database.

This is just a small example, actual table is much bigger and it will grow in size in time(that's why it needs to me dynamical).

Some fields need to be mandatory to fill in, so I made a column in database and as you can see hidden label (IDKarakteristike) is generated with the values True and False.

I need some kind of a jQuery to dynamically check if the label in the row is true or false and make textbox in the same row mandatory to fill in or not(depending on the label) on button click.

Can someone please help me with jQuery?

I need something like this, warning when the button is clicked.

```
 $('#myButton').on('click', function () {
            $("input").prop('required',true);
 });
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: please can you add html structure, or even better to publish example into [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Sorry here is the example https://jsfiddle.net/vc5dbtw9/8/

Comment: Why do you need javascript? add `requeired="required"` in the time you are generating the inputs using a server side decision.

Comment: It is all dynamical all control is in the database C# and asp just pass the values. So that's why I need jquery to do it :/
Here are meny characteristics some need to be mandatory and some do not.

Comment: In your example there are always two `span` elements with the class set to `IDKarakteristike`, one of them always contains number, so it it is not true that you render there only `True` or `False`

Comment: add the relevant code directly to the post and not as an external fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working example. Find the spans, get only the spans with boolean value, for each span find the parent row and then find the form element within this row:

```js
$(function () {
 $("#myButton").on("click", function () {
  // Loop all span elements with target class
  $(".IDKarakteristike").each(function (i, el) {
   // Skip spans which text is actually a number
   if (!isNaN($(el).text())) {
    return;
   }

   // Get the value
   var val = $(el).text().toUpperCase();
   var isRequired = (val === "TRUE") ? true :
        (val === "FALSE") ? false : undefined;

   // Mark the textbox with required attribute
   if (isRequired) {
    // Find the form element
    var target = $(el).parents("tr").find("input,select");

    // Mark it with required attribute
    target.prop("required", true);

    // Just some styling
    target.css("border", "1px solid red");
   }
  });
 })
});
```

```css
.IDKarakteristike {
    display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <div>
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr style="color:White;background-color:#507CD1;font-weight:bold;">
   <th scope="col">Characteristic</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">Description</th>
  </tr><tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
   <td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_0" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">PFD Total value</span>
                        

                    </td><td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_0" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">1</span>

                        
                
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label1_0" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">True</span>

                        
                    </td><td>
                        
                         

                         <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl02$txtBoxOpis" type="text" maxlength="4" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_0" margin-Left="100px" style="font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;" />
                      
                    </td>
  </tr><tr style="background-color:White;">
   <td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_1" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">PFD Wear </span>
                        

                    </td><td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_1" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">2</span>

                        
                
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label1_1" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">False</span>

                        
                    </td><td>
                        
                         

                         <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl03$txtBoxOpis" type="text" maxlength="6" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_1" margin-Left="100px" style="font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;" />
                      
                    </td>
  </tr><tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
   <td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_2" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">PFD Weight g/m²</span>
                        

                    </td><td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_2" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">3</span>

                        
                
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label1_2" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">False</span>

                        
                    </td><td>
                        
                         

                         <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl04$txtBoxOpis" type="text" maxlength="8" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_2" margin-Left="100px" style="font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;" />
                      
                    </td>
  </tr><tr style="background-color:White;">
   <td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_3" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">PFD Surface 
</span>
                        

                    </td><td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_3" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">5</span>

                        
                
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label1_3" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">True</span>

                        
                    </td><td>
                        
                         <select name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl05$ddlOpis" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_ddlOpis_3" margin-Left="100px" style="font-family:Georgia;height:35px;width:161px;">
    <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Proteco 
</option>
    <option value="2">Proteco  Oil
</option>
    <option value="3">Classic
</option>
    <option value="4">Natura
</option>
    <option value="5">No Surface t</option>

   </select>

                     
                      
                    </td>
  </tr><tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
   <td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_4" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">PFD  product
</span>
                        

                    </td><td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_4" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">9</span>

                        
                
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label1_4" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">True</span>

                        
                    </td><td>
                        
                         

                         <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl06$txtBoxOpis" type="text" maxlength="60" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_4" margin-Left="100px" style="font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;" />
                      
                    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>


    <input type="button" class="button" id="myButton" value="Save"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, me again. This code works fine but can you make one change to it.
When the textbox who is mandatory has some value written in it, there is no reason for it to have a red warning.  Thanks in advance !
@xxxmatko

Comment: Just change this line of code `target.prop("required", true);` to this `!target.val() && target.prop("required", true);`

Comment: Sorry but still no luck :(
I made a snippet https://jsfiddle.net/vc5dbtw9/61/
@xxxmatko

Comment: Ehm, I forgot the last line which change the border to red, so forget the last change and made this one: before this line `target.prop("required", true);` add this check `if(target.val()) {return;}`, here's the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nzx3tdgp/

Answer (score 1):

This is how to go to the previous TD and find the second span (or you can use class seletor for IDKarakteristike) and check its value to decide:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").each(function(){
     if ($($this).closest('td').prev('td').find("span").eq(1).html()=='true'){
        $(this).prop('required',true);
     }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vc5dbtw9/56/

Surround your html code with form tag and convert the button to submit and put the following script and you are good to go!

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function () {
       $('#MainContent_gvKarakteristike tr').each(function(e){
           var mandatory = $(this).find('.IDKarakteristike:last').text().toLowerCase();
           if(mandatory == 'true')
           {
               $(this).find('input,select').prop('required','required');
           }
           else
           {
               $(this).find('input,select').prop('required',false);
           }
       });
 });
```